# How to set the number of front page's promoted nodes?

Tags: nodes

Is it possible to set the number of front page's promoted nodes and thus display a pager?

Comment: you can use views to display all the promoted nodes with pager option, right from the views UI itself. Views has option to limit number of nodes being shown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Configuration -> System -> Site Information

In the Front Page section there is an option for 'Number of posts on the front page'

Comment: It is unbelievable this information is so hard to find on drupal.org ! Thanks a lot :)